# How to focus on a window with pygame?

Tags: python, window, pygame

I made a Python game using Pygame. I try to make it so when it starts, it loads the shell, and entering a raw input would display the pygame window and start the game so that I can make the game playable without having to close the shell. It works, however, the window starts minimized. The game is a simple "dodge the object" and has no pause what so ever. The game still runs in the background, possibly having the player hit multiple projectiles before the user realizes it. Is there a way to focus on the window?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you don't want the game to start, before the window is in fullscreen-mode, right?

When I try you attempt (starting through rawinput), my display is fullscreen from the start. Have you set everything correctly?

I suggest that you stop the game until there is an actual key-input (whatever controls you have set). Like this the player has the time to arrange everything to his liking before starting the game. Because, even if you figure out how to analyse the focus-issue: When the game starts, the window HAS focus, therefore this approach wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future who stumbles across this question:

As of 2022, pygame v2.1.2 has an experimental module `._sdl2` where: `Window.focus()` is used to make a window to be moved at the top and set focus. `Windows.focus()` supports optional `input_only` bool parameter for whenever the window should be moved at the top (False), or just collect input (True).